# error: an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected

Tags: sql

Getting the error: an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected from syntax below.

```
string Query = "SELECT User.First, User.Last, 
                   Details.Address1, Details.Address2, 
                   Details.County, Details.Country 
                FROM User 
                INNER JOIN Details 
                   on User.Details_DetailsID 
                WHERE User.Last ='" + cbUsers.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `INNER JOIN`, it's expecting a boolean result from a comparison operator.

You need to say something like this:

`ON column = column`

Perhaps `ON User.Details_DetailsID = Details.DetailsId`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put equality parameter in the inner join condition. 
     Please refer below string:

```
string Query = "SELECT User.First, User.Last, 
               Details.Address1, Details.Address2, 
               Details.County, Details.Country 
            FROM User 
            INNER JOIN Details 
               on User.Details_DetailsID = Details.Details_DetailsID
            WHERE User.Last ='" + cbUsers.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
```

Or you should check parameter data types and put case when conditions with typecase.