# Set Statement Truncated Dynamic SQL Only In Code

Tags: sql-server

I have a dynamic sql below

```
Declare @Sql varchar(max)
Set @Sql = 'select... where c='+@param+' and d=d' //some sql text more than varchar(4000)
```

when I use code to execute the sql like this

```
string text = @
' Declare @Sql varchar(max)
  Set @Sql = 'select... where c='+@param+' and d=d' //some sql text more than varchar(4000)'

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = text
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param","'strParam'"));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();//get error here.error is 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'jok_a'.
```

It's seems the dynamic sql been truncated in set statement.

I have a search online and know that implicit conversion can occur when concatenating a string in this situation, which make `varchar(8000)`  `varchar(4000)`. And as they suggest I changed `varchar(8000)` to `varchar(max)` but still get error.

I am not a big fan of using something like `@sql=@sql(4000 part) +'...'(rest part)`. Is there another way to resolve this if I just want to adjust sql?

Comment: any specific reason why you are assigning the select statement to variable `@Sql`? doesnt make sense based on the code you've shared

Comment: Find solution for `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'jok_a'` error first.... Please verify your query. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768204/error-an-expression-of-non-boolean-type-specified-in-a-context-where-condition for some idea

Comment: @Jesuraja As I understand, this error occurs because the query text was cut off.

Comment: Can you use the SQL Server profiler (or the profiling stored procedures) to confirm what is being sent to SQL Server? This will tell you whether the string is being truncated by SQL Server itself, or further up the chain, by your client code, or the connection library. Also, the dynamic SQL you are building looks a bit off with the `c=' + @param + '` bit, are you sure it isn't better to build the SQL text in its entirety at the client end rather than (presumably) using `sp_executesql`, and use command parameters as they are intended? Hint: this looks like a vector for a SQL injection attack.

Comment: @jojo You are doing from C#, right?

Comment: @Jesuraja if I use something like @sql=@sql(4000 part) +'...'(rest part), no error occurs. So I confirm my query is correct

Comment: @EdB I will try to use sqlprofiler but i not sure if I could catch the query when it have some error.

Comment: @Jesuraja Yes, I use C#

Comment: @jojo, if the error is coming from SQL Server, profiling will be able to catch the command. If you don't have access to the profiler (it's not included in the express version of SQL Server), you can use `sp_trace_create` to create a trace, `sp_trace_setevent` and `sp_trace_setfilter` to set the properties, `sp_trace_setstatus` to start and stop it, and `fn_trace_gettable` to view the results.

Comment: I use profiler and find below sql

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this:

No need of `DECLARE` and `SET` here, just remove it and use only **`SELECT`**  statement.

```
string text = @"select... where c=" + @param + " and d = d";
```

Comment: it work. but I really want to know why the issue happens? maybe I should raise another question.

Comment: You are concatenating query from C# and then passing to DB. In SQL only you need DECLARE and SET statements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your @param is varchar(4000)? You need to include in your concatenation at least one variable with (max).

For example

```
Declare @Sql varchar(max)
set @Sql = ''
Set @Sql = @Sql + 'select... where c='+@param+' and d=d' //some sql text more than varchar(4000)
```

Comment: @param is less than 20 chars

Comment: It's no matter what size it is. If you concatenat varchar(100) and varchar(20), the result will be varchar(100). By default, string constants which has less than 4000 symbols have type varchar(4000). So result type also will be 4000. But it there will be at least one operand with varchar(max), the result also will varchar(max).